# Parsing a tab delimited text file in C

Tags: c

so, i saw an older post that showed how to do this, but for some reason it seems it no longer works, my input file consists of a header row, and then 15 rows of input, each with 5 columns, first 2 are strings, the last 3 are ints, i have a struct to store them, and im trying to write the contents into an array of these structs

```
FName LName Credits Transactions Modifer
John Doe    83000   2   1
Jane Doe    64000   5   3
```

I tried

```
    struct customer cust = { NULL,NULL,0,0,0};
    char line[SIZE] = { 0 }, * ptr = NULL;
    cust.fName = malloc(15);
    cust.lName = malloc(15);
    printf("%d\n", &fp);
    if (NULL == (fp = fopen("../customers.txt", "r")))
    {
        perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (EOF != fscanf(fp, "%s", line))
    {
        ptr = strtok(line, "\\");
        cust.fName = ptr;
        printf("%s", ptr);
        while (EOF != (ptr = strtok(NULL, "\\")))
        {
            i++;
            printf("%s",ptr);
            if (i == 1)
                cust.lName = ptr;
            else if (i == 2)
                cust.miles = atoi(ptr);
            else if (i == 3)
                cust.years = atoi(ptr);
            else if (i == 4)
                cust.sequence = atoi(ptr);
        }

        i = 0;
        printf("After Reading: fName:[%s] lName:[%s] miles:[%d] years:[%d]\n", cust.fName, cust.lName, cust.miles, cust.years);
    }
```

For some reason, the `printf` within the inner while loop only prints `"(null)"`, and errors out when `i==2`
with the error

```
File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\inc\corecrt_internal_strtox.h
Line: 1772

Expression: _p != nullptr
```

I dont have any idea what that error message means, so i dont know what im doing wrong

Comment: The tab character is a white space character. So there is no sense to use fscanf To read a whole line.

Comment: Don't use `fscanf("%s",line)` to read a line [it will stop on each whitespace]. Use `fgets` instead. BTW, comparing against `!= EOF` for `fscanf` is _wrong_ [should be `== 1`], but, again, don't use it. And, using `EOF` with strtok is _completely_ wrong. Compare against `NULL`

Comment: @YSquared Yobozo Also this statement while (EOF != (ptr = strtok(NULL, "\\"))) is incorrect because NULL is not the same as EOF.

Comment: The reason i didnt do NULL, is because i had that and it caused the while loop to never run, im guessing because it was stopping at the white space as stated by craig,
Also, Craig, do you mind giving an example, im pretty new to using C and am unfamiliar with fgets

Comment: @YSquared Yobozo Instead of this while statement  while (EOF != fscanf(fp, "%s", line)) use while ( fgets( line, sizeof( line ), fp ) != NULL )

Comment: A tab character is `"\t"` not `"\\"` and I suggest the fuller `"\n\t"` to filter any trailing newline too.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow thanks, that fixed most the issues, after a few tweaks i got it workings

Comment: @WeatherVane Yea, after posting i did go and change to \t, thanks for the idea though, i just added in the \n :)

Comment: You'll need the `\n` if you read each line with `fgets` as suggested. It saves you a job.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, Craig, do you mind giving an example, im pretty new to using C and am unfamiliar with fgets

Okay. Because your code was a bit far off, I had to refactor it heavily.

Your code was only handling a *single* customer record. What you need to do is a separate `struct` instance for each line (i.e. customer). So, we want to use `realloc` to enlarge a dynamic array of our `struct customer`.

And, you have allocate memory [on the heap] for each string in a record (i.e. first and last names). So, we have to use `strdup`

Anyway, here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct customer {
    char *fName;
    char *lName;
    int miles;
    int years;
    int sequence;
};

int
main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char buf[1000];
    char *cp;
    char *bp;
    struct customer *list = NULL;
    int custcnt = 0;
    struct customer *cust;
    const char *delim = "\t\n";
    int field;

    fp = fopen("customers.txt","r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("error opening file");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (1) {
        cp = fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),fp);
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;

        // increase size of customer list/array by one
        list = realloc(list,sizeof(*list) * (custcnt + 1));
        if (list == NULL) {
            perror("malloc");
            exit(1);
        }

        // point to place for next customer
        cust = &list[custcnt];

        // advance customer count
        ++custcnt;

        // preclear the new record in case of a line that is malformed (i.e.
        // missing some data)
        memset(cust,0,sizeof(*cust));

        // loop through and store all customer record fields
        bp = buf;
        for (field = 0;  field < 5;  ++field) {
            cp = strtok(bp,delim);
            if (cp == NULL)
                break;
            bp = NULL;

            switch (field) {
            case 0:
                cust->fName = strdup(cp);
                break;

            case 1:
                cust->lName = strdup(cp);
                break;

            case 2:
                cust->miles = atoi(cp);
                break;

            case 3:
                cust->years = atoi(cp);
                break;

            case 4:
                cust->sequence = atoi(cp);
                break;
            }
        }

        printf("After Reading: fName:[%s] lName:[%s] miles:[%d] years:[%d]\n",
            cust->fName, cust->lName, cust->miles, cust->years);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd set `fName` and `lName` to `null` prior to starting the `strtok()` loop in case there's a bad line so later code won't crash.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I had debated that before posting but I was trying to keep it simple since I was already far afield of OP's original code. But, you're right--it's a good addition. I've added a `memset` to get the `calloc` effect for the `realloc` [which is what I normally do in my own code].